# OpenNLP Coreference Resolution (German)

Tags: nlp, text-mining

I need to do coreference resolution for German texts and I plan to use OpenNLP to perform this task.

As far as I know OpenNLP coreference resolution does not support the German language.

Which components/data do I need to adapt the code such that it is possible to perform coreference resolution for German texts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Coreference Resolution for German Texts](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/955/coreference-resolution-for-german-texts)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. It is a question specific to OpenNLP and the other question is about coreference resolution tools in general

Comment: I can't see the difference between these questions. Both ask for a coreference tool besides OpenNLP, because OpenNLP doesn't support it.

Comment: This question asks about training methods to add the coref resolution functionality to OpenNLP and the other one asks for available tools for German coreference resolution. This is a big difference!

Comment: OK. I suggest rewording these to make them more distinct. I think many readers will not get the nuance of what you are asking in each case.

Answer (score 1):

From an older version of the [OpenNLP README](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/README.html):

> **Training the Tools**
>
> There are training tools for all components expect the coref component. Please consult the help message of the tool and the javadoc to figure out how to train the tools.
>
> The tutorials in our wiki might also be helpful.
>
> The following modules currently support training via the WordFreak opennlp.plugin v1.4 (http://wordfreak.sourceforge.net/plugins.html).
>
> - coreference: org.annotation.opennlp.OpenNlpCoreferenceAnnotator (use opennlp 1.4.3 for training, models are compatible)
>
> **Note:** In order to train a model you need all the training data. There is not currently a mechanism to update the models distributed with the project with additional data.

As you can see, OpenNLP does not provide training tools for the coreference component. However, it seems at one point it was possible to train new models for OpenNLP's coref component using the third-party WordFreak plugin... however, it hasn't been updated in over a decade, so your mileage may vary.