# Coreference Resolution for German Texts

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

Does anyone know a libarary for performing coreference resolution on German texts?

As far as I know, OpenNLP and Stanford NLP are not able to perform coreference resolution for German Texts.

The only tool that I know is [CorZu](http://www.cl.uzh.ch/static/news.php?om=view&nid=163) which is a python library.

Comment: Your question is very concise, yet it'd be nice to hear from you what you've tried so far, or even see some example of what you're trying to achieve. Would you mind adding some further information to your post?

Comment: possible duplicate of [OpenNLP Coreference Resolution (German)](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/954/opennlp-coreference-resolution-german)

Comment: I already added additional information to the post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a couple of tools that may be worth a look:

- Bart, an open source tool that have been used for several languages, including German. [Available from the website](http://www.bart-coref.org/)
- Sucre is a tool developed at the University of Stuttgart. I don't know if it's available easily. [You can see this paper about it](http://hnk.ffzg.hr/bibl/acl2011/CoNLL-ST/pdf/CoNLL-ST3.pdf).